# Matplotlib help: Formatting a scatter plot to be square

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot where the axis are both limited at -100 and 100. However, when I graph the data, I always get an unappealing looking plot that is rectangular with incorrect axis labels. I'd like the plot to be a square with -100 and 100 as the last axis labels. Does anyone have advice for fixing this formatting issue?

My code is as follows:

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np

r = scipy.stats.pearsonr(x_val, y_val)
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_val, y_val, s=75, color='green', edgecolor='black',  linewidth = 2, alpha=0.4)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
matplotlib.pyplot.axvline(0, c='#262626', linewidth=1.5, alpha=0.9)
matplotlib.pyplot.axhline(0, c='#262626', linewidth=1.5, alpha=0.9)
matplotlib.pyplot.grid(linewidth=1, color='#bfbfbf')
matplotlib.pyplot.xticks(np.arange(-100, 100, 20.0),fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', 
    fontname='Helvetica')
matplotlib.pyplot.yticks(np.arange(-100, 100, 20.0),fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', 
    fontname='Helvetica')
matplotlib.pyplot.text(-95, 85,'Pearson\'s r: %.3f'%r[0], fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', 
    fontname='Helvetica')

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: i'm not seeing this problem. try adding a figsize `fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(figsize=(X, X))` with X being a size in iches

Comment: Thanks. This gets me halfway to solving the problem. The graph is now a square, but I still have the unappealing spacing of the ticks on the y-axis resulting in the big blank rectangles at the top and bottom of the plot

Comment: i can't reproduce it. sorry

Comment: `np.arange(-100, 101, 20.0)`?

Comment: ax.set_ylim(-100,100) ended up being the way to go. Thanks for the help!